# ?attr/actionBarSize inflation causing crash

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Both the following lines seem to crash the app on inflation.

```
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    // or 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Any ideas? i am trying to create my own bar, the default size of a standard action bar.

Exception below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com...., PID: 30039
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com....../com.....}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010071 a=-1}
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010071 a=-1}
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010071 a=-1}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:761)
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7039)
at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7220)
at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1926)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1824)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1823)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:860)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
```

Comment: can you try to ctrl+click on the `?attr/actionBarSize` see if its initialized in R file

Comment: put your xml file so we can see properly what is an error

Comment: `<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/top_bg">`                                                 this one works fine for me .. may you took wrong layout...

Comment: It works fine in the andriod studio, yes it is found in the android R. But it does not seem to inflate on run time. :(

Comment: Someone just deleted their answer which actually worked.. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material
```

instead of

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

Comment: It will work because it is like normal value difened in dimens but in this case it is already included by library in dimens_material.xml.Check this https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/HEAD/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/dimens_material.xml